# SignalR 2.1 Cordova - WebSockets always timeout on connection (android <4.4)

Tags: android, cordova, websocket, signalr

Our Cordova (PhoneGap) SignalR app consistents fails through to Long Polling transport despite have WebSockets available (via the https://github.com/mkuklis/phonegap-websocket plugin).  The plugin has worked with our other WebSockets applications so this seems specific so SignalR.

```
09-02 15:43:21.328: I/Web Console(2774): [15:43:21 GMT+0000 (GMT)] SignalR: Negotiating with 'https://abx.xyz/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.4&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22modelbrokerhub%22%7D%5D'. at https://abx.xyz/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.1.js:81
09-02 15:43:21.364: I/Web Console(2774): [15:43:21 GMT+0000 (GMT)] SignalR: Connecting to websocket endpoint 'wss://abx.xyz/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.4&connectionToken=XbDetAQ5JXGPEwClfACiTW%2FuJq1NcXSErfEtHxyfMtdDTsTH%2BbzMPiH8tR1mvvbaJn6SsrvdKtnuTrdPmbCs3LrW%2Bxl6VTY4HmgvNerPUNEkqL0t0%2FwcLIx0FfVCjsZt&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22modelbrokerhub%22%7D%5D&tid=1'. at https://abx.xyz/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.1.js:81
09-02 15:43:26.372: I/Web Console(2774): [15:43:26 GMT+0000 (GMT)] SignalR: webSockets timed out when trying to connect. at https://abx.xyz/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.1.js:81
09-02 15:43:26.372: I/Web Console(2774): [15:43:26 GMT+0000 (GMT)] SignalR: Closing the Websocket. at https://abx.xyz/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.1.js:81
```

Has anyone else seen this issue?

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/knowledgecode/WebSocket-for-Android ? I my experience, it works better than phonegap-websocket.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need WSS support on Android 2.3 which that plugin doesn't seem to support.  Thank you for you comment though!